# How can I toggle a class of a specific element in each item of an *ngFor list in angular?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components

I have a parent component that has a `*ngFor` to render all instances of a child component items stored in the database.
They are all collapsed by default. & can be expanded by calling a toggle function which passes in the click event of the child component instance.

I want to add a button in the parent component that should toggle all child components instances that was rendered by the parent component.

**Parent Component**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ToggleAllVersions()">Expand All</a>
<version *ngFor="let version of versionService.versions | async" [version]="version"></version>
```

.

```
@Component({ selector: 'parent', templateUrl: './parent.component.html',})

ToggleAllVersions(){
    //add class to specific element in each version of versionService.versions
}
```

**Child Component**

```
<div class="first-element">
     <div class="//toggle class here by calling ToggleAllVersions() in parent componant."></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using `@ViewChildren` as follows

**Parent Component**

```
@ViewChildren(VersionComponent) private allVersions!: QueryList<VersionComponent>;
isAllExpanded = false;

  expandAndCollapse(){
    this.isAllExpanded = !this.isAllExpanded;
    this.allVersions.forEach(v=>v.isExpanded = this.isAllExpanded);
  }
```

**Child** (Version) **Component**

```
 isExpanded = false;
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle **all** child components on a button click, you can use a flag that will represent the current status of all items.

#### parent.component.ts

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class ParentComp {
 areItemsCollapsed = true;

 ToggleAllVersions(){
  this.areItemsCollapsed = !this.areItemsCollapsed;
 }

}
```

#### parent.component.html

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ToggleAllVersions()">Expand All</a>
<version 
 *ngFor="let version of versionService.versions | async"
 [ngClass]="{ 'is-collapsed': areItemsCollapsed }"
 [version]="version"
></version>
```

#### child.component.css

```css
:host.is-collapsed {
 /* ... Styles applied when the item is collapsed */
}
```

---

If you want to toggle the class for a **specific element**, you will have to change some stuff in the parent component.
You can make use of a map object where each key is the `id` of the child, and the value is a `boolean` that indicates whether the child component should be collapsed or not.

#### parent.component.ts

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class ParentComp {
 collapsedItemsMap: { [k: string]: boolean | undefined } = {};

 toggleChildVersion (childItem){
  this.collapsedItemsMap[childItem.id] = !this.collapsedItemsMap[childItem.id]
 }
}
```

#### parent.component.html

```html
<version 
 *ngFor="let version of versionService.versions | async"
 (click)="toggleChildVersion(version)"
 [ngClass]="{ 'is-collapsed': collapsedItemsMap[version.id }"
 [version]="version"
></version>
```